# Python code in crawling RSS services website at terminal logcat was non understand

Tags: python, web, web-crawler

I'm getting started with reptiles and trying to perform a second crawling exercise based on Feedly(Feedly RSS is the first time I think): it don't open website to see the news, just the title, source link and update time)

This is my code, the first tried with python.

I was thinking that I might need crawling on my subscribe root websites and might need to write a Scrapy script and use MangoDB or Excel/CSV for this?

> In my this case, I was even think that I should develop a macOS App to show the crawling result and I was designed the App UI, or use Python QT and learned QT。

I tried to print the links and the title first, but Feedly should tap twice that show Source page，so i choose Feedly‘s entry.

Python code:

```py
def get_url(url):  # 获得每一页新闻的原始链接

    news_url = requests.get('urls',headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(news_url.text, 'lxml')

    links = soup.select('#.*?\=_16b.*?\:2.*?\:d02fd57c_entry_title')

    for link in links:
        href = link.get('href')
     print(href)

#if __name__ == '__main__':
#    urls = ['https://feedly.com/i/entry/'.format(number) for number in range(1,16)]
#    for url in urls:
#        get_url(url)
#        time.sleep(2)
```

logcat:

```sh
 File "aa2.py", line 17
    print(href)
              ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

I think i don't need use Feedly API，Because i was use chrome to see json info that only have title and sub read, but i was not tried, so i choose web crawling.

I found Feedly "check"（Use Chrome）json only have title and unread, no "update time" and category".

[I found Feedly jeson was only have title and unread, no "update time" and category"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqxtI.jpg)

Here is my all code:

```py
import requests
import time
from lxml import etree
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# import pymongo MongoDB数据库
# import xlwt EXCEL
# import csv CSV

headers = {
           'cookie': '',  # 传入cookies
           'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.34 (KHTML, like Gecko)' 
           'Version/11.0 Mobile/15A5341f Safari/604.1'
}

def get_url(url):  # 获得每一页新闻的原始链接

    news_url = requests.get(url, headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(news_url.text, 'lxml')

    links = soup.select('#.*?\=_16b.*?\:2.*?\:d02fd57c_entry_title')

    for link in links:
        href = link.get('href')
        get_newsinfo(href)

    get_url(url)

def get_newsinfo(url):

    news_title = requests.get(url, headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(news_title.text,'lxml')

    news_titles = soup.select('#.*?\=_16b.*?\:2.*?\:d02fd57c_entry_title')

    news_links = soup.select('#.*?\=_16b.*?\:2.*?\:d02fd57c_entry_title')

    for link in  news_links:
        href = link.get('href')
        return href

    news_updatetimes = soup.select('#>*?\=_16b03.*?\:2.?*\:5de7e37_entryHolder > div.u100Entry > div.entryHeader > div.fx.metadata > span:nth-child(3)')

    for news_title, news_link, news_updatetime in zip(news_titles, news_links, news_updatetimes):
        data = {
            'NewsTitle':news_title.get_text(),
            'Updatetime':news_updatetime.get_text(),
            'NewsLink':news_link.get.text()
        }
        print(data)

    get_newsinfo(url)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    urls = ['https://feedly.com/i/entry/'.format(number) for number in range(1, 14)]

    for url in urls:
       get_url(url)
    time.sleep(2)

#    wbdata = []

#    newsList = ['ifanr', 'huxiu', '36kr']
#
#    if newsList[0] = wbdata:

 #       wbdata = requests.get('http://****.com',headers)

# def news_title(url):

#    news_info = requests.get('https://feedly.com/v3/streams/contents?streamId=user%**********-dfb0-46c7-b688-***********%2Fcategory%2F%E7%A7%91%E6%8A%80&count=20&unreadOnly=true&ranked=newest&similar=true&continuation=16b01e292f7:3277d:5de7e37&ck=1559135018763&ct=feedly.desktop&cv=31.0.357', headers)
> ********* is my privacy, not show.

#    d = news_info.json() tried use json

#    artititles = d['title']
#    print(len(artititles))

#    for artititle in artititles:
#        yield artititle['title']
```

I hope news_title news_updatetime news_links.

Here is my logcat:

```sh
FelixdeMacBook-Pro:Desktop felixxiong$ python3 feedlynewsupdate.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "feedlynewsupdate.py", line 61, in <module>
    get_url(url)
  File "feedlynewsupdate.py", line 23, in get_url
    links = soup.select('#.*?\=_16b.*?\:2.*?\:d02fd57c_entry_title')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1376, in select
    return soupsieve.select(selector, self, namespaces, limit, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/soupsieve/__init__.py", line 114, in select
    return compile(select, namespaces, flags, **kwargs).select(tag, limit)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/soupsieve/__init__.py", line 63, in compile
    return cp._cached_css_compile(pattern, namespaces, custom, flags)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/soupsieve/css_parser.py", line 214, in _cached_css_compile
    CSSParser(pattern, custom=custom_selectors, flags=flags).process_selectors(),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/soupsieve/css_parser.py", line 1113, in process_selectors
    return self.parse_selectors(self.selector_iter(self.pattern), index, flags)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/soupsieve/css_parser.py", line 946, in parse_selectors
    key, m = next(iselector)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/soupsieve/css_parser.py", line 1100, in selector_iter
    raise SelectorSyntaxError(msg, self.pattern, index)
soupsieve.util.SelectorSyntaxError: Malformed id selector at position 0
  line 1:
#.*?\=_16b.*?\:2.*?\:d02fd57c_entry_title
^
```

Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm actually the author of the CSS implementation (Soup Sieve) in Beautiful Soup 4.7+.

The reason it is failing is because you are not following the CSS specification. Now, I'm not aware of exactly what you are trying to target, so I cannot suggest working selectors, but I can explain why Soup Sieve is failing for you.

The error in your example `#.*?\=_16b.*?\:2.*?\:d02fd57c_entry_title` is failing because it sees an id token `#`, but is not followed by an id. Instead it sees the start of a class `.`, and that is also invalid as it is followed by `*`. In short, there is a lot wrong with the selector, but the error is just reporting the first.

You will need to use CSS escapes for invalid characters in ids, classes, etc.  If we try  to run such a selector through a browser, you'll see that it fails as well:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#.*?=_16b.*?:2.*?:d02fd57c_entry_title' is not a valid selector.
    at <anonymous>:1:10
```